# SQL Job Management

Tags: sql-server

I've been handed a project to document and manage all of our SQL agents jobs.  I found this great tool from Idera but the only problem that I have its not exportable.  I need an application that can provide me with a gant chart or timeline so that I can share with our developers.  Thanks for your help

Comment: can you share more requirements about what you need to docuemnt? is it just the start times of your jobs?

Comment: In the past, we have issue with server contention for resources from jobs that were run in parallel.  Idera works great but you need to have admin privileges and our environment it cannot be allowed.  I need a tool that I can publish for example on our intranet so our devs can view the scheduled jobs and allocate a block of time to prevent contention on the server.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a good tool to do this. The Idera tool is the same one from SQL Sentry under an OEM license.

If you are looking for an export, why not try a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I hit something like this a long time ago. It seems like an obvious thing to do, and I *think* I've heard of tools that might do this, but I've never used or actually found one.

What I did back when was attempt to roll my own. This required building queries against the various sysjob* tables in msdb (particularly sysjobs and sysjobschedules), which required some serious deciphering -- some of their structures are pretty obtuse. Security/access will be an issue, as by default very few permissions are granted to those tables.  (It is possible to add a Role and suitable permissions in msdb, but would the DBAs let you?)

If you can't find a tool somewhere, building your own may be the only way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the permissions, but Capacity Manager from Quest software did have a view of the SQL Agent jobs.

unfortunately, if the tools require admin access, then you are going to be forced to roll your own solution and request read access to the msdb database.